# Blending the whole page

Tags: html, css

I would like to bland the whole page i.e. all layers with background gradient.

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(251, 234, 188, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 114, 136, 1) 100%);
}

.blend {
  opacity: 0.4
}

.blend1 {
  opacity: 0.4
}

.blend2 {
  background-image: url("img_tree.gif");
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  opacity: 0.4
}
```

```html
<h1>The background-blend-mode Property</h1>

<div id="myDIV">
  <b class="blend">Note:</b>
  <p class="blend1"> test text test text test text test text test text</p>
  <div class="blend2 blend"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Is there a way to do this with a lot of html elements? Currently, it is possible to use opacity or mix-blend-mode for very close elements.

Comment: you mean you don't want to use CSS?

Comment: Do you want to blend the entire page, or just content of `#myDIV`?

Comment: I would like to use css if possible. yes, I would like to blend the entire page with the content. Content can be images, text, everything.

Comment: have you tried : `html {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
    rgba(251, 234, 188, 1) 0%,
    rgba(0, 114, 136, 1) 100%
  );
}
body {
  mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
}` and is it what you look for ?

Comment: html, body , content( linear-gradient), div, div, div, ...., div, img (it should be blended with content(linear-gradient)), span (it should be blended with content(linear-gradient))...

Comment: example from my earlier comment , https://jsfiddle.net/3j98vgL6/ blending once body with html .

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mix-blend-mode: soft-light;` to all the elements using `*` selector, which will blend over the gradient. I have added gradient to entire webpage, by selecting `html` element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html {
      height: 100%;
      background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(251, 234, 188, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 114, 136, 1) 100%);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    
    #myDIV {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      /*background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(251, 234, 188, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 114, 136, 1) 100%);*/
    }
    
    * {
      mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
    }
    
    .blend2 {
      background-image: url(https://dbdzm869oupei.cloudfront.net/img/sticker/preview/3685.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>The background-blend-mode Property</h1>

  <div id="myDIV">
    <b class="blend">Note:</b>
    <p class="blend1"> test text test text test text test text test text</p>
    <div class="blend2 blend"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the effect on the entire html content like this

```css
html {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(251, 234, 188, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 114, 136, 1) 100%);
  opacity: 0.4
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>The background-blend-mode Property</h1>


  <b>Note:</b>
  <p>test text test text test text test text test text</p>
  <div></div>
</div>
```